# using static array when calls external interface

Tags: c, static, global

I have a question about using pointer of static variables as input arguments between c files.
I though that i have to declear and define array as a global since the array pointer is tranmitted to external function in another c file.
As you can see in below, both two ways are complied well by my compiler without warning and it makes me confused.

Which one is correct? I need your help.

**check.c**

```
#include "my_library.c"
const static float my_array[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
main(void)
{
  int index;
  index = runsearch(2.5, my_array);
  ...
}
```

**my_library.h**

```
extern int runsearch(float value, float* tableaddr);
```

**my_library.c**

```
int runsearch(float value, float* tableaddr)
{
   ...
   return index;
}
```

*or*

**check.h**

```
extern const float my_array[3];
```

**check.c**

```
#include "check.h"
#include "my_library.h"
const float my_array[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
main(void)
{
   int index;
   index = runsearch(2.5, my_array);
   ...
}
```

**my_library.h**

```
extern int runsearch(float value, float* tableaddr);
```

**my_library.c**

```
#include "check.h"
int runsearch(float value, float* tableaddr)
{
   ...
   return index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object declared at file scope doesn't need to be declared as `extern` for a pointer to it to be passed to functions in other modules.  It's no different than passing the address of a local variable to a function in another module.

The main thing that `static` does is prevent other modules from referencing that object *by that name*.

So both approaches will work, although the first version using `static` would be preferable in this case since the other module doesn't need to access that name.

Comment: Re the first sentence: Not only does an object declared at file scope not need to be declared `extern`, it does not need to be declared at file scope. For an object to be passed to another function anywhere, it only needs to exist.